# Java Script - How do delete JSESSIONID manually in chrome when i close the browser?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies, extjs

In chrome browser, when I close the browser JSESSIONID is not deleted, due to that application is directly getting inside without redirecting to login page.

Cookie Details from developer Tools:

[image]

I tried to delete the this JESSIONID cookie by the below ways

1. delete document.cookie
2. document.cookie=""

But values are not able to delete. Can you tell me exact method to delete the cookies in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.cookie = 'JESESSIONID=; Max-Age=0;'
```

Because `document.cookie = xxx` just append or rewrite a cookie field.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it didn't worked :(.